# USQL / VS 2017 - Can I create parsing script from SSMS CREATE script?

Tags: sql-server, azure, u-sql

I have a flat file that I imported to SQL Server and set all the variable types.

I'd like to manipulate the same flat file in an Azure environment and maybe reuse the CREATE script if possible (to set variable types).

Note : I'm using VS 2017.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do an extraction?  If yes, see [Create U-SQL EXTRACT Script Automatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/08/08/create-u-sql-extract-script-automatically/).

And if you want to create a table in U-SQL, you can add a `CREATE TABLE AS` statement to the `EXTRACT`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706197.aspx